# Denormalizar datos en R

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente código

```
 testset1 <- datos4[1,]

 prueba <- neuralnet::compute(net, testset1[,1:10])

 prueba$net.result
 predicted=prueba$net.result * abs(diff(range(datos4[,11]))) + min(datos4[,11])

 print(predicted)
```

El resultado me da 0.42.

Como tendría que hacer para de normalizar y obtener el dato compuesto

Saludos y gracias

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con el dato compuesto? Podrías agregar un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida esperada? Saludos.